# any way to compare an integer variable to a list of integers in if statement

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is a way to compare an integer variable to a list of integers in if statement as we can do it in SQL WHERE CLAUSE,

```
WHERE MY_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

and I want to use the same functionality if it exists in c#

```
if(myid in (1,2,3,4,5,6)){}
```

this might seem a dummy question but it would save me a lot of time if existed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an array aggregate directly in your `if` statement, like this:

```
if (new[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}.Contains(id)) {
}
```

Note: you need to add `using System.Linq` in order for this to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var numbers = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6};

if (numbers.Contains(myId))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
if (intArray.Contains(3))
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `List<T>.Contains`, if you want to do this to keep a track of values you have already entered, you could use `HashSet<int>` as the `Add` methods returns true if the value is added:

```
var numbers = new HashSet<int>();

if (numbers.Add(myNumber))
{
    // myNumber has just been inserted into numbers
}
```

The `HashSet` also has the added benefit of being designed to quickly find specific values inside it based on hash, and with `int`, the hash is simply the `int` itself.

And it has `Contains`:

```
if (numbers.Contains(myNumber))
{}
```

`IEnumerable` also has a `Contains` extension method for anything else:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

using the `Contains` Extension method you can achieve this eaisly:

```
var myNumberList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};

// check using the Contains extension method

if(myNumberList.contains(TARGET_NUMBER))
{
 // do your stuff here
}
```

from the official MSDN article:

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx